# eCommerce Drupal

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

I want to sell eBooks on one of my websites. I want to know which module is best and simplest for this purpose. I am confused between [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) and [eCommerce](http://drupal.org/project/ecommerce) module

Simplicity is the major concern for me.
Please Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know any other module for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 for Ubercart

Ubercart and e-commerce are both good solutions for running an eCommerce site on Drupal. I have mostly used Ubercart, and I think that the strong community supporting Ubercart makes it the obvious choice for me.

To suit your specific case, Ubercart comes bundled with the "File Download" ([brief tutorial here](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/3345/selling_files)) module, which allows you to add less conventional "products" (like an eBook download!) to your store.

Also, Ubercart has reached a final release (2.0), while e-commerce is still in a release candidate phase (rc13, as of this posting). I'm sure it is still suitable for a production site, but it may have some quirks and bugs still.

Ubercart has always been my go-to. I think it can be both simple and feature-rich if you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

From my research, you will want to use UberCart if you decide to use Drupal for your CMS.   I haven't used it personally, however, from what I have been reading online, this is the only way to go if you are definately using Drupal.

Comparison article between the two:
[Link](http://www.slayerment.com/blog/drupal-ecommerce-vs-ubercart-which-shopping-cart-better)

There are multitudes of open source shopping cart systems out there, that are not hosted on Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also opencart platform, it is completely opensource and has mulitple add-ons to make your website powerful and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Both Ubercart & eCommerce are best you can chose any of it. For best solutions. You can visit: [eCommerce Development](http://builtbyblank.com/ecommerce-web-development/)